# I want to send a DM through a discord bot to the author of the message recieved in "on_message" function. How can i do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
load_dotenv("token.env")
token = os.getenv("Token")
bot = commans.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.author == bot.user:
          return
     if message.content.startswith("!"):
          await bot.process_commands(message)
          return
     else:
          author = message.author
          await message.channel.send(message.content)
```

How can i change the code in line 15 to send the message to "author"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Member.create_dm()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.create_dm) for this. You can modify your code as follows:

```
from discord.ext import commands
load_dotenv("token.env")
token = os.getenv("Token")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.author == bot.user:
          return
     if message.content.startswith("!"):
          await bot.process_commands(message)
          return
     else:
          c = await message.author.create_dm()
          await c.send(message.content)
```

You also misspelt `commands` in `bot = commands.Bot(...` :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly!!! How should i do to make it an embed message, so it looks better?

Comment: You do not actually need to use "create_dm", "send" already works by itself.

Comment: And what about embed messages?

Answer (score 0):

You could use await ctx.author.send() so that whoever runs the command would get it sent in there dms

```
from discord.ext import commands
load_dotenv("token.env")
token = os.getenv("Token")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.author == bot.user:
          return
     if message.content.startswith("!"):
          await bot.process_commands(message)
          return
     else:
          author = message.author
          await ctx.author.send(message.content)
```